# How to trigger a JavaScript function after “Bootstrap: collapse plugin” transition is done

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I use this method

```
$jq('#indexClassData').on('hidden', function () {
    // Do something…
    expandIndexClass();
})
```

It does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: what u want to do actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for the "hidden.bs.collapse" event, not "hidden".

Scroll down to "Events" here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage

Answer (score 0):

thank you but  i use another  method 
   // ahmed taha to fix issue of documet coolapse 
   $jq('#indexClassData').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {

expandIndexClass()
})